# Style the wp7 (Mango) keyboard

Tags: styles, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I want to style (actually just change the color) on the built in keyboard in an wp7 application. I am creating a Silverlight project, and using a  as the input, and this has the default styled keyboard on focus. Is there a way to style this keyboard? I have tried looking at the xaml style TargetTypes, but I don't see any valid options for a keyboard!

Any idea on how to style a WP7 (Mango) keyboard?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is currently not possible. the keyboard is part of the system that is outside of the scope of your controls, much like the launchers and choosers. The only control you have over the keyboard is the [input-scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521152%28VS.92%29.aspx), which allows you to select keyboards appropriate for numeric, URL entry etc ...

Comment: Thanks! Not the answer I was hoping for, but now we know!